# I am trying to generate a random hexadecimal number in python and send it over UDP

Tags: python, sockets, udp

Here is my python code:

```
import socket
data = bytes.fromhex("47 A2 62 19 20 00 00 00 00")
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, 0) 
ADDRESS = ("192.168.0.1",9000)
s.connect(ADDRESS)
s.send(data)
```

I want to put 4 random hexadecimal bytes after "47 A2 62 19 20 00 00 00 00". For example "47 A2 62 19 20 00 00 00 00 20 1E 4A 72".
I wonder what to do. Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`random.randbytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randbytes) can generate random bytes for you. Note that a hexdecimal pair is two bytes, not one byte, so you'll need eight random bytes, not four:

```py
import random
data = bytes.fromhex("47 A2 62 19 20 00 00 00 00") + random.randbytes(8)
```

Comment: Note, that [`random.randbytes()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randbytes) is available in python 3.9+, for lower versions there's an alternative [`secrets.token_bytes()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#secrets.token_bytes)